# Trying to create a user name and password to log onto next tkinter window. If user and pass correct login button goes to next screen

Tags: python, authentication, tkinter, new-window, data-entry

Here are the labels and buttons I am using, I want the login button to check for passwords in code, then if correct go to the next screen.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# Main window of Application
root.title("Please Login")
root.geometry("300x150")
root.config(background='lightblue', borderwidth=5)


# Creating Label Widget
myLabel1 = Label(root, text="Username :", background='lightblue')
myLabel2 = Label(root, text="Password :", background='lightblue')
# Entry fields
username_1 = Entry(root)
password_1 = Entry(root, show='*')


# Putting labels onto screen

myLabel1.grid(row=0, column=0)
myLabel2.grid(row=1, column=0)

# Entry field Locations
username_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
password_1.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Here i have the command quit button but having a hard time with the command for login to go to next window.

```
# Creating Buttons
loginButton1 = Button(root, text="Login")
cancelButton3 = Button(root, text="Cancel", command=quit)

# Putting buttons onto screen

loginButton1.grid(row=6, column=1)
cancelButton3.grid(row=7, column=1)


# New window

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What do yo need help with? What does "having a hard time" mean?

Comment: Sorry Bryan you are right. I guess my question is, How do i add a user name and password for a user, and when they use the login button it will switch to a new screen if correct credentials.

Answer (score 0):

That is a lot for one question... I'll try to give you an idea of how you can do this though. I usually do not create a whole new window; I simply change the already existing window.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# Main window of Application
root.title("Please Login")
root.geometry("300x150")
root.config(background='lightblue', borderwidth=5)

# Possible Login
possible_users = {'user1': 'user1_pass', 'user2': 'user2_pass'}  # dictionary of corresponding user name and passwords

# StringVars
the_user = StringVar()  # used to retrieve input from entry
the_pass = StringVar()

# Creating Label Widget
myLabel1 = Label(root, text="Username :", background='lightblue')
myLabel2 = Label(root, text="Password :", background='lightblue')
bad_pass = Label(root, text="Incorrect Username or Password")

# Entry fields
username_1 = Entry(root, textvariable=the_user)
password_1 = Entry(root, show='*', textvariable=the_pass)


# Putting labels onto screen

myLabel1.grid(row=0, column=0)
myLabel2.grid(row=1, column=0)

# Entry field Locations
username_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
password_1.grid(row=1, column=1)


def login(user):
    forget_login_window()
    next_window(user)


def check_login():
    requested_user = the_user.get()
    try:
        if possible_users[requested_user] == the_pass.get():
            login(requested_user)
        else:
            bad_pass.grid(row=2, column=1)
    except KeyError:
        bad_pass.grid(row=2, column=1)


loginButton1 = Button(root, text="Login", command=check_login)
cancelButton3 = Button(root, text="Cancel", command=quit)

# Putting buttons onto screen

loginButton1.grid(row=6, column=1)
cancelButton3.grid(row=7, column=1)


# New window

def forget_login_window():  # forget all the grid items.
    username_1.grid_forget()
    password_1.grid_forget()
    myLabel1.grid_forget()
    myLabel2.grid_forget()
    loginButton1.grid_forget()
    cancelButton3.grid_forget()
    bad_pass.grid_forget()


def next_window(my_user):
    root.title(my_user)  # desired changes here 
    #  you will need to create your tkinter objects (buttons, labels etc) in global and pack / grid / place them here.


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Shane, when you say place bad passcode here does this create the "incorrect login/password" screen if the username and or password is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, you could create a new TopLevel() object to create a pop up window. I would probably just create a label that says "Incorrect login or user ID" in the global space. Then place the code to grid it where the ``` pass ``` and comment is at. Of course, you will need to .grid_forget() it later but you can just add that to the forget_login_window() function, and if it is never .grid(), it will not have any ill effects. I'll edit the code above to show you.

Comment: I only used one message for the bad username and password as it is best practice for security, but you could make the messages different.